# DBFlow: How to migrate tables from an other database?

Tags: database-migration, dbflow

I have some columns of a table in an "old" database that I want to migrate to a new one, using DBFlow. DBFlow provides the `@Migration` annotation for databases, but it seems it only works to migragte tables in the same database.

What is the best approach to import columns into the a new/different database using DBFlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to migrate between different databases. One need to copy/convert/migrate by hand.